# Socket server in java

Tags: java, sockets

I have a simple client/server chat in java using Socket. The problem is the program connect to each other but I can't get/receive data from both side for some reasons. When I disconnect the server the client give me an error " Connection reset" which shows that they are connected but they don't exchange data.

The code are the same code taken from Java Tutorial taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication3;

/**
 *
 * @author Amr
 */
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class KnockKnockServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4440);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println(Inet4Address.getLocalHost());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine, outputLine;


        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
             outputLine = "heelo";
             out.println(outputLine);
             if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                break;
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class KnockKnockClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket kkSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            kkSocket = new Socket(Inet4Address.getLocalHost(), 4440);
            out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fromServer;
        String fromUser;

        while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
            if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
                break;

            fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
        if (fromUser != null) {
                System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                out.println(fromUser);
        }
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        kkSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a single thread on both the client and the server that reads from their respective `BufferedReader`, using the [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method, which blocks.

Since both the client and server are expecting to read from one another *before* either of them sends anything, they'll both just sit there and block. You either need to fork and have a thread that reads from the `BufferedReader` and one that writes to the `PrintWriter`, or you have to have:

```
outputLine = "heelo";
out.println(outputLine);
```

outside of your while loop.

Answer (score 5):

After setting up the connection, the first thing your server does is

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
```

that is, it waits for the client to say something.

The first thing your client does is

```
while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null)
```

that is, it waits for the server to say something.

Make one of the two send something first and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The bit you're missing from that tutorial is this block:

```
// initiate conversation with client
KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();
outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
out.println(outputLine);
```

Currently, you are not initialising the conversation, hence the socket read blocking pointed out by other posters.